# Diagnose why rsync is or is not copying certain files

Tags: rsync

I have a script that uses `rsync` to fetch files from a remote server, then process them. These local copies are not deleted between runs, so `rsync` should only have to fetch *new* files. However, it seems that `rsync` is downloading every file every time, even when neither cached local copy nor server copy has changed, and I can figure out why.

Is there some command-line argument for `rsync` that will help me diagnose why a given file is or is not being copied this run? I've tried `-v`, but it doesn't seem to give me the information I need. Something like:

```
> rsync --diagnose-why-files-copied remotehost:/remote/path ./local/path/
'remotehost:/remote/path/file1':
  Destination file './local/path/file1' does not exist; copying.

'remotehost:/remote/path/file2':
  Destination file './local/path/file2' exists...
  Destination file size does not match source file size; copying.

'remotehost:/remote/path/file3':
  Destination file './local/path/file3' exists...
  File sizes match...
  Destination file modification date does not match source file modification date; copying.

'remotehost:/remote/path/file4':
  Destination file './local/path/file4' exists...
  File sizes match...
  File modification dates match...
  No change detected; skipping.

> rsync -c --diagnose-why-files-copied remotehost:/remote/path2 ./local/path2/
'remotehost:/remote/path2/file1':
  Destination file './local/path2/file1' does not exist; copying.

'remotehost:/remote/path2/file2':
  Destination file './local/path2/file2' exists...
  Destination file checksum does not match source file checksum; copying.

'remotehost:/remote/path2/file3':
  Destination file './local/path2/file3' exists...
  File checksums match...
  No change detected; skipping.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-ii` is what I was looking for. The `--itemize-changes` option, short form `-i`, causes a diagnostic message to be printed for each file that was updated or changed identifying what was done with it and why. Specifying the option twice causes it to also print the message for files which are not changed at all.